# Whitelist IPs In Nginx Virtual Host File Country Blocking

Tags: apache, nginx, virtualhost, whitelist, nginx-location

In Nginx I am checking to see if an IP is coming from a blocked country. If it is then the visitor gets a 403. I need the capability to add whitelisted IPs to allow them in even if they are part of the blocked countries.

I would prefer to whitelist the IPs at the nginx.conf location so I don't need to update 30+ virtual host files. How can I do this?

In each of the nginx virtual host files in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

```
location / {
    if ($allowed_country = no) {
      return 403;
    }

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

The country list is created in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
## GEOIP settings
    geoip_country /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;
    map $geoip_country_code $allowed_country {
      default yes;
      RU no;
      BR no;
      UA no;
      PH no;
      IN no;
      CN no;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have an filter on geoip country as well as IP Adress you need [geo module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html) Resulting in something as:

```
location / {
   if ($allowed_country = no) {
     return 403;
   }

   if ($allowed_ip = no) {
      return 403;
   }

   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Plus the mapping in nginx.conf

```
geo $allowed_ip {
    default        no;

    127.0.0.1      yes;
    192.168.1.0/24 yes;
}
```

This should be possible but the [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) directive has to be under the http context.

I would suggest to have an [include](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) in every vhost, having the geoip settings in a separate file, to be more flexible.

Comment: Hi Ben, 
This geoip is already in a separate file (GeoIP.dat) and country blocking is working correctly. The include is already a part of the nginx.conf file.

I am looking for a way to add whitelisted IPs to this functionality but I do not know the syntax for including it either in the map $geoip_country_code $allowed_country function in the nginx.conf file or in each virtual host file. 

That is what I need assistance with. Thanks!

Comment: I see, I misunderstood the question then. The way to do that would be the [geo module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html).  I will update my answer

Comment: Hi Ben, when I implement this or similar solutions I get a 403 from all IP addresses. It looks like the geo $allowed_ip denies all IP addresses by default. Is there no way to not set a default = no and set if ($allowed_ip = yes) { try files ...

Comment: You could skip the default and override allowed_country `geo $allowed_country {
    127.0.0.1      yes;
    192.168.1.0/24 yes;
}`